# Better way to iterate through list and store output in a new list

Tags: python, list, loops

I am a beginner in python and I would like your opinion on a more sophisticated way to write the code that follows. I want the code to iterate through the whole list (x) of items, count how many times each item appears and store the output in a new list (z). Here is the code (it works as it is) :

```
x = ["apple", "orange", "cherry", "apple"]

def new_list(a):
    z=[]
    for i in x:
        y = x.count(i)
        (z.append(y))
    return z

print(new_list(x))
```

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest to do a list comprehension:

```
>>> x = ["apple", "orange", "cherry", "apple"]
>>> [x.count(val) for val in x]
[2, 1, 1, 2]
>>>
```

Or even better with `map`:

```
>>> [*map(x.count, x)]
[2, 1, 1, 2]
>>>
```

Answer (score 1):

With using `list.count()` order of your programming is `O(n^2)` and with `Counter and hashmap` order of your programmer is `O(n)`.
Try this:

```
x = ["apple", "orange", "cherry", "apple"]

[x.count(i) for i in x]
# [2,1,1,2]
```

Or use `Counter`:

```
from collections import Counter
dct = Counter(x)
# Counter({'apple': 2, 'orange': 1, 'cherry': 1})

[dct[i] for i in x]
# [2, 1, 1, 2]
```

Check Runtime: *(`Counter` is faster than `list.count()`)*

[image]

Comment: @U12-Forward wait for cheching for larg list :)))

Comment: @U12-Forward this is two approach, not mine and yours, and I'm sure `Counter is O(n)` and `count is O(n^2)`

Comment: Well `Counter` does not fulfill Op's desired output.

Comment: @U12-Forward can see counter 1000 faster

Comment: How about `map`

Comment: @U12-Forward you can check your self `map` only short phrase for `for-loop` and in `map` use `list.count()`.

Comment: It should be quicker

Comment: @u12 check and remove this comment, when not sure, don't post I'm sure :))

Answer (score 0):

Try using the Counter class:

```py
from collections import Counter
x = ["foo", "bar", "foo", "foo"];
z = Counter(x)
print(z)
# Output: {"foo": 3, "bar": 1}
```

Comment: "Try using the Counter library" -- `Counter` is a class not a library.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Counter class in collections. So iterate over input list and then find count of every element.

```
from collections import Counter
x = ["apple", "orange", "cherry", "apple"]
c = Counter(x)
print([c[item] for item in x])
#[2, 1, 1, 2]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Counter subclass of the collections module:

```
from collections import Counter

x = ["apple", "orange", "cherry", "apple"]


counter = Counter(x)
z = list(counter.values())

print(z) #[2,1,1]
```

I didn't use `count` because it may not be good for performance which is also pointed out by [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2600208/15120502).